# How to calculate distance travelled from velocity vector and angle?

Tags: homework-and-exercises

I am trying to get the distance a projectile travels, so I can display it in my program.

I'm sort of new to physics, but I've tried looking this up.

I'm not getting the right results however, and me being new to physics, I'm not sure if I'm just using the wrong formula or what.

This is the formula I have tried using:

[image]

As far as I've read, a projectile launched at 15 degrees would travel the same distance as one launched at 75 degrees, however when I run the calculation I get two different distances for those two instances.

Is this not the correct formula, or maybe I'm using it wrong?

These are the values I get for 15 degrees and 75:

15:
velocity vector = (5,-19)
magnitude = 20
vCos = -15.2
vSin = 13
gravity = 9.8
output = 41

75:
velocity vector = (19,-5)
magnitude = 20
vCos = 18.4
vSin = -7.8
gravity = 9.8
output = 2

The projectile starts on the ground and gets launched at the specified angle over a flat surface.

Not sure where I'm going wrong.

All help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: In most/all programs, trigonometric functions have their arguments in *radians*, not *degrees*.

Comment: You may be right. On the wiki it specified they were using degrees. But I'll give it a go.

Comment: You were right about it needing to be in Radians. Thanks :)

Comment: Please don't edit the title of a question to indicate that it was solved. That's what accepting an answer is for. (that's the green checkmark)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, since "The projectile starts on the ground and gets launched at the specified angle over a flat surface", $y_0 = 0$ and the equation reduces to:

$$ d = \frac{v^2sin(2\theta )}{g} $$

Now you can see that $d$ will be the same for $\theta $ and $90 - \theta$, such as 15 and 75 degrees; however, this is not true for the more general equation in the question where the starting point and ending point are not necessarily the same height.

But I think your problem is here:

> 15: velocity vector = (5,-19) magnitude = 20 vCos = -15.2 vSin = 13 gravity = 9.8 output = 41
>
> 75: velocity vector = (19,-5) magnitude = 20 vCos = 18.4 vSin = -7.8 gravity = 9.8 output = 2

Why do you have negative values?

Comment: I have negative values because of the coordinate system in my program. For the projectile to move up the x had to be negative. I could take the absolute value if the negative value is causing a problem.

Comment: how did you get "20vCos = -15.2" and "20 vCos = 18.4", one positive and the other negative?

Comment: I was able to tinker around with my project after I got home from work, and it now works. You were right that I needed to use the reduced equation, and Kvothe was right that I needed to use Radians instead of degrees. One last question, what is the unit that the distance I get back measured in? Is it meters? 

Also, thank you for all your help :)

Comment: if the velocity is in m/s and g is in m/s^2, then d will be in meters